# whats wrong with my code? unexplainable syntax error

Tags: java

I keep on getting a syntax error on `double h= (19*a + b – d – g + 15)%30;` where it says delete d - g?

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 public class mathpowers {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 String yearString =
 JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a year");

 double y = Double.parseDouble(yearString);

 double a=y%19;
 double b=y/100;
 double c=y%100;
 double g = Math.round((8*b + 13)/25);
 double h= (19*a + b – d – g + 15)%30;
 double j= c/4;
 double k = c%4;
 int m = (a + 11*h)/319;
 double r = (2*e + 2*j-k-h+m+32)%7;
 double n=(h-m +r+90)/25;
 double p=(h – m + r + n + 19)%32;
```

Comment: Where have you defined `d`?

Comment: There's no `d` variable defined in your code. Define it and the compiler error might leave.

Comment: how about `}` at the end?

Comment: What is the EXACT error message?

Comment: And as Obi-wan said unto Skywalker: _Use the parenthesis_.

Comment: What on earth are you calculating?

Comment: some stupid algorithm for to find the easter egg day of a the year, and yeah i left the paranthesis out but thanks i didnt realize i didnt have a d

Comment: In the code that you've posted, the minus-signs are not ASCII minus-signs, but rather, are some sort of funky Unicode character. Are you using Microsoft Word to edit your source-code?

Comment: missing 2 closing braces, and 'd' undefined (as pointed out by Luiggi).

Comment: no im using eclipse and it registers that minus sign o.0 edit: wow your right thanks for pointing out that im using this funky unicode character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minus sign you had used is in different encoding when I copied the same in my editor it showing as

```
 double h= (19*a + b ? d ? g + 15)%30;
```

This is causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

d is undefined

add the following line (setting d to whatever it is supposed to be)

double d=0;

Answer (score 1):

**d is undefined**

```
double h= (19*a + b – d – g + 15)%30;
```

**e is undefined**

```
double r = (2*e + 2*j-k-h+m+32)%7;
```

**Why you are naming the variable as a,b,c...**

**Variable names are too bad in your code**

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes as below - undefined variables 'd' and 'e' and 'm' needs to be cast

```
String yearString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a year");

double y = Double.parseDouble(yearString);

double a = y % 19;
double b = y / 100;
double c = y % 100;
double g = Math.round((8 * b + 13) / 25);
double d = 0;
double h = (19 * a + b - d - g + 15) % 30;
double j = c / 4;
double k = c % 4;
int m = (int) ((a + 11 * h) / 319);
int e = 0;
double r = (2 * e + 2 * j - k - h + m + 32) % 7;
double n = (h - m + r + 90) / 25;
double p = (h - m + r + n + 19) % 32;
System.out.println(p);
```